# What to look for in bicycle travel cases

Tags: storage

My wife and I are taking a trip to Japan in several months and that got me thinking, what should someone look for in a bike case when travelling? I won't be taking one on this trip (not in the shape I want to be in quite yet), but it could be beneficial information for others and myself in the future. The range of prices that bike cases span is pretty broad so knowing what to look for could potentially save you money and a broken bike.

Doing a little bit of research myself, I noticed that some airlines will also supply you with boxes for travel. Are these safe or is it worth getting your own?

Bicycling in a foreign country (or a different city for that matter) seems like an amazing way to see parts of it that you normally wouldn't get a chance to see.

Comment: I would expect to find a bike when I look in a bicycle travel cases!

Comment: You always have the problem of what do you do with the case when you get there.

Comment: If it was me, I'd seriously look at a folding or [S&S coupling](http://www.sandsmachine.com/) bike so that the case could be smaller and maybe even avoid the extra airline charges. http://surlybikes.com/frames/travelers_check_frame/ http://www.bikefriday.com/touring http://us.dahon.com/bikes/1672/tournado http://us.dahon.com/bikes/1649/speed-tr

Comment: Personally I'd look into rental options before I went through the trouble and expense of getting a bike in and out of airports, customs, etc.

Comment: http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2210.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure it is sized to your bicycle.  The one time I flew a commercial airline with my bicycle I planned to use my father's travel case.  But with the wheels, cranks, seatpost and handle bar/stem totally removed my frame would not fit.  (A 64cm road frame).

Because it was for a one time, one way trip I got some shipping boxes from my local bike shop.  I got creative with the foam and packing tape.  Bike made the trip just fine :)